# Help with creating temperature humidity script

Tags: linux, python, raspberry-pi, temperature

I am a completely inexperienced A level student trying to get to grips with python to complete an assignment. I have been given a week to complete it- I have very little knowledge of what to do and have no experience with coding - I am truly stuck and will probably seem very stupid to people on his forum.

I have to create a temperature and humidity logger with a raspberry pi and DHT22 sensor. I am to write a script that produces a loop that sleeps for 10 seconds - i will run the script for two days to collect data enough to produce graphs. So far the code i have is this and its not working - probably for some obvious reasons- The data needs to come out in two columns on a leafpad file.

```
# Assign header details to STRING variables - change manually 
txt_studentid = '999'     
txt_pi_location = '999.99999'  
txt_pi_latitude = '999.99999'   
txt_pi_longitude = '999.99999'   

import Adafruit_DHT   
pin = 4   
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22 
# Import Time module import time 
# open file to write   
f = open('/home/pi/y_data.txt','w') 
f.write(txt_studentid)   
f.write('\n')   
f.write(txt_pi_location)   
f.write('\n')   
f.write(txt_pi_latitude) 
f.write('\n') 
f.write(txt_pi_longitude) 
f.write('\n') 
f.close() 

while True: 
   # store off the date and time details for this   
   sample num_month = time.localtime().tm_mon   
   num_day = time.localtime().tm_mday   
   num_hour = time.localtime().tm_hour   
   num_min = time.localtime().tm_min   
   num_sec = time.localtime().tm_sec   
   num_humidity, num_temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)     

txt_month = str(num_month)   
txt_day = str(num_day)   
txt_hour = str(num_hour)   
txt_min = str(num_min)   
txt_sec = str(num_sec)   
txt_humidity = str(num_humidity)   
txt_temperature = str(num_temperature)     

f = open('('/home/pi/my_data.txt','a')   
f.write(txt_month)     
f.write(',')   
f.write(txt_day)   
f.write(',')   
f.write(txt_hour)   
f.write(',')   
f.write(txt_min)   
f.write(',')   
f.write(txt_sec)     
f.write(',')   
# write the temperature and humidity to file   
f,write(txt_humidity)   
f.write(',')   
f,write(txt_temperature)   
f.write(',') 
# write new line   
f.write('\n')    
# close the file   
f.close()   
# wait for ten seconds   
time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: just to say I type in sudo python my_script.py and there is no error message it

Comment: The `f = open` statements can use some corrections. In the first you open a file called `y_data.txt` and in the second you are appending to a file called `my_data.txt`. Also in the second `f = open` statement you have a `('` to much.

Comment: Your while loop is incorrect, it falls into an infinite loop.

Answer (score 0):

You're almost there. The code you wrote is a bit unnecessarily long but that is normal if you're new and don't know the tricks and the right functions ;)
It is, however, still working with some minor changes!
You need to indent everything after the line where you read out the sensor. Otherwise it is not included in your loop and you keep reading the values but you're not writing them.
Then two comments got messed up, first you commented out `import time` which you definitely need and second at the comment right after `while True:` you moved `sample` into the next line.
You also wrote `f,write(...` two times. Note the `,` instead of `.`
Finally your last call to `open` still contains the `('` that Lambert was already talking about.
The last three problems are syntax issues and should actually be pointed out by python itself.

I would also suggest to put the filepath into its own variable somewhere at the top so you can change it more easily.
Furthermore it is not necessary to keep a variable for both the numeric and the string version of all the parts of the timestamp. Just get the time once and then read its attributes within a format string. See [format string syntax](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-string-syntax) and have a look at my code.

This is how I would write the script:

```
import time
import Adafruit_DHT

# Assign header details to STRING variables - change manually 
txt_studentid = '999'
txt_pi_location = '999.99999'
txt_pi_latitude = '999.99999'
txt_pi_longitude = '999.99999'

filepath = '/home/pi/my_data.txt'
pin = 4
sensor = Adafruit_DHT.DHT22
# Import Time module import time
# open file to write
with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
    f.write(txt_studentid + '\n')
    f.write(txt_pi_location + '\n')
    f.write(txt_pi_latitude + '\n')
    f.write(txt_pi_longitude + '\n')

line_template = ('{time.tm_mon},{time.tm_mday},{time.tm_hour},{time.tm_min},' +
                 '{time.tm_sec},{hum},{temp}\n')
while True:
    # get current time
    sampletime = time.localtime()
    # sample sensor values
    humidity, temperature = Adafruit_DHT.read_retry(sensor, pin)
    # append time and values to file
    with open(filepath, 'a') as f:
        f.write(line_template.format(time=sampletime,
                                     hum=humidity,
                                     temp=temperature))
    # wait 10 seconds
    time.sleep(10)
```